# Ruby on Rails Routes Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller called `head_buses_controller.rb` and in my routes have mapped it like so `map.resources :head_buses`

This results in URLs being http://domain.com/head_buses

I would however would like to have the URLs with a dash `-` instead of an underscore `_`.

Is it possible to have the URLs with the dashes go to the head_buses controller?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this one:

```
resources :head_buses, :as => 'head-buses'
```